# How to find and replace all occurrences of "(percentage)%" in a text file and replace with a user supplied Integer

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

I am trying to parse through a text file with regex finding percentages as strings and replacing the findings with the percentage multiplied by a user supplied integer. If the user inputs 400, then the code should return "120 x 8, 180 x 6, etc"

Tried doing a replace but it replaces all findings with the same string.

$body = "30% x 8,    45% x 6,    55% x 4,   60% x 2,   65% x 1,   70% x 1,   75% x 1,   80% x 1, 72.5% x 4,   70% x 4,   67.5% x 4,   65% x 4"

```
$regex1 = "(\d+(\.\d+)?%)"
$regex2 = "(\d+(\.\d+)?)"
$regex3 = "\bx \d{0,2}\b"
$regex4 = "\b% x \d{0,2}\b"
$percent = $body | select-string  -Pattern $regex1 -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { [string]$_.Value } | % {"$_,"}
$reps = $body | select-string  -Pattern $regex4 -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } | % {"$_,"}
$weights = $body | select-string  -Pattern $regex1 -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } | select-string -Pattern $regex2 -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { ([int]$_.Value / 100) }
$reps_percent = $body | select-string  -Pattern $regex4 -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { [string]$_.Value } |select-string -Pattern $regex3 -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { [string]$_.Value } | % {"$_"}
```

User inputs: 400
Output:
"120 x 8, 180 x 6, etc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In PowerShell *Core*** (v6.1+), you can take advantage of the fact that the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375)'s replacement operand can now perform *dynamic* replacements, via a *script block* to which the match at hand is passed as `$_`, as a [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) instance:

```
$body = '30% x 8,    45% x 6,    55% x 4,   60% x 2,   65% x 1,   70% x 1,   75% x 1,   80% x 1, 72.5% x 4,   70% x 4,   67.5% x 4,   65% x 4'

# Sample user input (the value for which to calculate percentages).
$value = 400 

$body -replace 
  '\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)% x (\d+)',
  { '{0} x {1}' -f ([double] $_.Groups[1].Value * $value / 100), $_.Groups[2].Value }
```

The above yields (each percentage is replaced by the value that results from applying the percentage to `$value`):

```
120 x 8,    180 x 6,    220 x 4,   240 x 2,   260 x 1,   280 x 1,   300 x 1,   320 x 1, 290 x 4,   280 x 4,   270 x 4,   260 x 4
```

---

**In *Windows* PowerShell**, you have to make direct use of the .NET framework's `[regex]` type:

```
$body = '30% x 8,    45% x 6,    55% x 4,   60% x 2,   65% x 1,   70% x 1,   75% x 1,   80% x 1, 72.5% x 4,   70% x 4,   67.5% x 4,   65% x 4'

$scalePercentage = 400 

[regex]::Replace(
  $body,
  '\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)% x (\d+)',
  { param($m) '{0} x {1}' -f ([double] $m.Groups[1].Value * $scalePercentage / 100), $m.Groups[2].Value }
)
```

Note how parameter declaration `param($m)` is used to declare the `Match` instance that is passed to the script block (`$_` is *not* defined int this case); alternatively, you could forgo the parameter declaration and use `$args[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do without regex:

```
$body  = "30% x 8, 45% x 6, 55% x 4, 60% x 2, 65% x 1, 70% x 1, 75% x 1, 80% x 1, 72.5% x 4, 70% x 4, 67.5% x 4, 65% x 4"

$userInput        = 400

$calculationArray = $body -split ','
$body             = ''

foreach( $pattern in $calculationArray ) {
    $percent = @($pattern -split '%')[0] -as [int]
    $result  = $userInput * ($percent / 100)
    $body   += $result.ToString() + @($pattern -split '%')[1] + ', '
}

$body.Trim(', ')
```