# How can I replace certain characters (and not others) between delimiters and across newlines, using Regex in Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, batch-file, delimiter, powershell-5.1

Here is a sample:

```
: [
          {
            "yearGroupId": 13,
            "educationPhaseEnum": 2,
            "name": "Year Group 12",
            "label": "YG 12"
          },
          {
            "yearGroupId": 14,
            "educationPhaseEnum": 2,
            "name": "Year Group 13",
            "label": "YG 13"
          }
        ]
```

I want to remove the line breaks, and all quotes. I only want to do this between the strings ': [' and '        ]'. So the desired output would look like this:

```
[      {        yearGroupId: 13,        educationPhaseEnum: 2,        name: Year Group 12,        label: YG 12      },      {        yearGroupId: 14,        educationPhaseEnum: 2,        name: Year Group 13,        label: YG 13      }    ]
```

I've tried `Powershell -NoProfile "(Get-Content -Raw .\allacts.txt) -replace '(?<=\u003a\u0020\u005b).*[\n\r\u0022].*(?=\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u005d)', '' | Out-File -FilePath allacts.txt -Force -Encoding ASCII"`

and about a hundred other things... but can't get my head around how it's meant to work. What do I have to do to get Powershell to replace these characters within these bounds? In other places in the file I need the line breaks.

Thanks.

Edit: Yep, this is JSON data. The issue is that there are duplicate keys (I can't change that). Converting it to a CSV results Powershell ignoring duplicate keys and picking one of them to go into the output CSV. Directly importing the JSON into Excel (where I need it to go) results in Excel rejecting it as it can't handle duplicate keys.

So, I decided to just glom everything into one value and use Power Query to sort it out at the other end (using the commas as delimiters).

Comment: That looks like JSON data, so what are you going to do with it?

Comment: are you trying to break your Json or something?

Comment: You can certainly use a single regex for this because the left-hand and right-hand delimiters are different strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task requires a *dynamic* [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation operation, which *Windows PowerShell* (`powershell.exe`) - unlike *PowerShell (Core) 7+* (`pwsh`) - cannot provide directly:

- You need to identify the block of interest in your input file...
- ...and then perform the desired transformations *on that block only*.

<sup>Update: As [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71150842/45375) shows, non-dynamic single-`-replace` operation solutions using *look-around assertions* - as you attempted - are possible - but they are somewhat mind-bending.</sup>

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57454838/45375) discusses dynamic replacements in more detail, but applied to your case this means (the assumption is that you're calling from outside PowerShell, such as from `cmd.exe` / a batch file):

```sh
powershell.exe -NoProfile -c "[regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw .\allacts.txt), '(?s): \[.+?\r?\n        \]', { param($match) $match.Value -replace '[\r\n\"]' }) | Out-File -FilePath allacts.txt -Force -Encoding ASCII"
```

- For an explanation of the block-matching regex passed as the 2nd argument to  [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace) and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/7PeTsp/1).
- The regex used inside the 3rd argument, the dynamic replacement script block (`{ ... }`), is `[\r\n"]`, which matches all CR (`\r`), LF (`\n`), and `"` characters, and since it is used with `-replace` without a replacement operand, effectively *removes* them.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise it needed a completely different approach. Good to know I wasn't going to get anywhere trying to rearrange this or that character, good job I asked the question!

Comment: @NeMo, well, as Wiktor's answer shows, a solution with look-around assertions alone _is_ possible - but it is somewhat mind-bending.

Comment: Ha. Either way I wasn't going to work out out myself!

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the two plain string pattern regex replacements:

```
(Get-Content -Raw .\allacts.txt) -replace '(?s)(?<=: \[.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*? ])' | Out-File -FilePath allacts.txt -Force -Encoding ASCII
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%28%3F%3C%3D%3A%20%5C%5B.*%3F%29%5B%5Cr%5Cn%22%5D%28%3F%3D.*%3F%20%5D%29&i=%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22yearGroupId%22%3A%2013%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22educationPhaseEnum%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Year%20Group%2012%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22label%22%3A%20%22YG%2012%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22yearGroupId%22%3A%2014%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22educationPhaseEnum%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Year%20Group%2013%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22label%22%3A%20%22YG%2013%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D&r=). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - `RegexOptions.Singleline` enables `.` to match any chars including newline chars
- `(?<=: \[.*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `: [` string and then any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `[\r\n"]` - CR, LF or a `"` char
- `(?=.*? ])` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there are any zero or more chars as few as possible followed with a space + `]` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Or, if you have `: [.."...".: [ ... ]` like strings, and you want to remove the chars only in between the closest `: [` and  `]` you will need to use

```
(Get-Content -Raw .\allacts.txt) -replace '(?s)(?<=: \[(?:(?!: \[).)*?)[\r\n"](?=.*? ])' | Out-File -FilePath allacts.txt -Force -Encoding ASCII
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%28%3F%3C%3D%3A%20%5C%5B%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%3A%20%5C%5B%29.%29*%3F%29%5B%5Cr%5Cn%22%5D%28%3F%3D.*%3F%20%5D%29&i=%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22yearGroupId%22%3A%2013%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22educationPhaseEnum%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Year%20Group%2012%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22label%22%3A%20%22YG%2012%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22yearGroupId%22%3A%2014%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22educationPhaseEnum%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Year%20Group%2013%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22label%22%3A%20%22YG%2013%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D&r=) (see *Context* tab). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - `RegexOptions.Singleline` enables `.` to match any chars including newline chars
- `(?<=: \[(?:(?!: \[).)*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `: \[` - `: [` string
  - `(?:(?!: \[).)*?` - any char, zero or more but as few as possible times, that does not start a `: [` char sequence
- `[\r\n"]` - CR, LF or a `"` char
- `(?=.*? ])` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there are any zero or more chars as few as possible followed with a space + `]` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Matches are removed here.

Or,

```
(Get-Content -Raw .\allacts.txt) -replace '(?s)(\G(?!^)|: \[)(.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*? ])', '$1$2' | Out-File -FilePath allacts.txt -Force -Encoding ASCII
```

or

```
(Get-Content -Raw .\allacts.txt) -replace '(?s)(\G(?!^)|: \[)((?:(?!: \[).)*?)[\r\n"](?=.*? ])', '$1$2' | Out-File -FilePath allacts.txt -Force -Encoding ASCII
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%28%5CG%28%3F!%5E%29%7C%3A%20%5C%5B%29%28%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%3A%20%5C%5B%29.%29*%3F%29%5B%5Cr%5Cn%22%5D%28%3F%3D.*%3F%20%5D%29&i=%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22yearGroupId%22%3A%2013%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22educationPhaseEnum%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Year%20Group%2012%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22label%22%3A%20%22YG%2012%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22yearGroupId%22%3A%2014%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22educationPhaseEnum%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Year%20Group%2013%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22label%22%3A%20%22YG%2013%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D&r=%241%242) (do not forget to click *Context* tab there). Here

- `(?s)` - `.` matches any chars now
- `(\G(?!^)|: \[)` - Group 1 (`$1`): end of the previous match or `: [` string
- `((?:(?!: \[).)*?)` - Group 2 (`$2`): any char, zero or more but as few as possible times, that does not start a `: [` char sequence
- `[\r\n"]` - CR, LF or `"`
- `(?=.*? ])` - a check that there is space + `]` somewhere on the right.

In this case, matches are replaced with Group 1 + Group 2 values.

Replace literal spaces with `\s*` (zero or more whitespaces) or `\s+` (one or more whitespaces) in the pattern if you mean to match any (amount of) whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The other one is more readable but there may be situations in which it can't be used for some reason (I don't know)

Comment: @NeMo I might overcomplicated the pattern, what about just `'(?s)(?<=: \[.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*? ])'`? I added this one to the answer and explained the solution difference.